# Can't find null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, nullreferenceexception, mediator

I have another project with almost the exact same setup that works fine. I don't know where this null reference is coming from. None of the variables in the signature are null when I set breakpoints and look at them in VS.

Callstack

> ReportBuilder.Application.dll!ReportBuilder.Application.Templates.TemplateHelper.GetTemplateReport(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable template, int fiscalYear, int period, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 40    C#
> ReportBuilder.API.dll!ReportBuilder.API.Controllers.TemplateController.GetTemplateReport(int FiscalYear, int Period, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable Sites, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 39  C#
> [Lightweight Function]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync.__Logged|12_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker invoker)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync() Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync() Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next, ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()   Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync.__Logged|17_1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker invoker)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerRequestDelegateFactory.CreateRequestDelegate.AnonymousMethod__0(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)  Unknown
> Server.Shared.dll!Server.Shared.Services.RequestLogContextMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext)   Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.Use.AnonymousMethod__2()  Unknown
> Server.Shared.dll!Server.Shared.Services.ServiceExtensions.AddSharedConfiguration.AnonymousMethod__4_2(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> next)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.Use.AnonymousMethod__1(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.DefaultFilesMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)   Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)   Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll!Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext) Unknown
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll!Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext httpContext, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.UseMiddleware.AnonymousMethod__2(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.VsContentMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)    Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.ProcessRequestAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context context)   Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>.ProcessRequestAsync()   Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.HandleRequest() Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Execute()   Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()  Unknown
> Callstack

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetTemplateReport(IEnumerable<long> template, int fiscalYear, int period, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        return await _ReportHelper.GetReportBytes(new TemplateReport(fiscalYear, period, template, _Mediator), cancellationToken);
    }
```

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetReportBytes(IReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            IReport report2 = report;
            IReportBuilder reportBuilder = _ReportBuilder;
            reportBuilder.SetData(await report2.GetReportData(cancellationToken));
            TemplateBuilder templateBuilder = new TemplateBuilder();
            templateBuilder.GetReportOptions(report2.GetReportOptions(new ReportOptions()));
            templateBuilder.SetReportHeaders(report2.GetReportHeaders(new List<ReportHeader>()));
            foreach (ReportColumnSection reportColumnSection in report2.GetReportColumnSections(new ReportColumnSectionsBuilder()))
            {
                templateBuilder.AddColumnSection(reportColumnSection);
            }

            foreach (ReportRowSection reportRowSection in report2.GetReportRowSections(new ReportRowSectionsBuilder()))
            {
                templateBuilder.AddReportSection(reportRowSection);
            }

            templateBuilder.SetRowFormulas(report2.GetRowFormulas(new List<RowFormulaConfig>()));
            _ReportBuilder.SetConfiguration(templateBuilder.Build());
            _ReportBuilder.SetFinalizeCallBack(delegate (IWorksheet x)
            {
                report2.ReportFinalize(x);
            });
            return _ReportBuilder.BuildByteArray();
        }
```

```
using ReportBuilder.Application.Templates.Queries;
using GrapeCity.Documents.Excel;
using MediatR;
using Reporting.Shared;

namespace ReportBuilder.Application.Templates.Reports;
public class TemplateReport : IReport
{
    private readonly IMediator _Mediator;
    private int FiscalYear;
    private int Period;
    private IEnumerable<long> Templates = Enumerable.Empty<long>();

    public TemplateReport(int fiscalYear, int period, IEnumerable<long> templates, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _Mediator = mediator;
        FiscalYear = fiscalYear;
        Period = period;
        Templates = templates;
    }
```

Comment: The debugger should tell you which one is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
public TemplateHelper(IMediator mediator, IReportHelper reportHelper)
    {
        _Mediator = mediator;
        _ReportHelper = reportHelper;
    }
```

I was missing that IReportHelper in the signature somewhere else. Idk why it couldn't tell me that.